# Summarize this jquery possible?

Tags: jquery

I'm new in jquery. with this code , i think is ugly, can anyone help to improve this to shorter version? Because the actual code is more than 6 control, to ease you to see the code i remove the rest. So the actual code is more ugly :(

```
    $('#targetDay_0__Assigned , #targetDay_1__Assigned').hide();
        if ($('#targetDay_0__Assigned').is(":checked")) { 
            $('#lbltargetDay_0__Assigned').addClass("ui-state-active"); 
        }

        if ($('#targetDay_1__Assigned').is(":checked")) {
            $('#lbltargetDay_1__Assigned').addClass("ui-state-active");
        }


        $('#lbltargetDay_0__Assigned').click(function (e) {
            $('#targetDay_0__Assigned').click();
            $('#lbltargetDay_0__Assigned').removeClass("ui-state-active");
            if ($('#targetDay_0__Assigned').is(":checked")) {
                $('#lbltargetDay_0__Assigned').addClass("ui-state-active");
            }
        });

        $('#lbltargetDay_1__Assigned').click(function (e) {
            $('#targetDay_1__Assigned').click();
            $('#lbltargetDay_1__Assigned').removeClass("ui-state-active");
            if ($('#targetDay_1__Assigned').is(":checked")) {
                $('#lbltargetDay_1__Assigned').addClass("ui-state-active");
            }
        });
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review and belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: As felix said, you came to wrong zone. Anyway, i guess your problem is also from html. Please post also that code, maybe we can improve it

Comment: @Felix Kling, Ah, sorry. i don't know that. will post to other codereview, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this could work:

```
var targets = [], labels = [], totalElements = 6;

function changeState(index) {
    if (targets[index].is(":checked")) { 
        labels[index].addClass("ui-state-active"); 
    } else {
        labels[index].removeClass("ui-state-active");
    }
}

function click(index) {
    labels[index].click(function (e) {
        targets[index].click();
        changeState(index);
    });
}

for(var index = 0; index<=totalElements; index++) {
    //store the elements for later access
    targets.push($('#targetDay_' + index + '__Assigned').hide());
    labels.push($('#lbltargetDay_' + index + '__Assigned'));

    //initial state change
    changeState(index);
    //bind the click events
    click(index);
}
```

then if you wanted to access them elsewhere just refer to the index of the element i.e. targets[4];

Answer (score 0):

Create Variables for the different elements in the DOM at the top then use that variables instead accessing the DOM via jQuery again and agian

```
        var targetDay0Assigned = $('#targetDay_0__Assigned'); 
        var targetDay1Assigned = $('#targetDay_1__Assigned'); 
        var lbltargetDay0Assigned = $('#lbltargetDay_0__Assigned'); 
        var lbltargetDay1Assigned = $('#lbltargetDay_1__Assigned'); 

        targetDay1Assigned.hide();
        targetDay0Assigned.hide();
        if (targetDay0Assigned.is(":checked")) { 
           lbltargetDay0Assigned.addClass("ui-state-active"); 
        }

        if (targetDay1Assigned.is(":checked")) {
            lbltargetDay1Assigned.addClass("ui-state-active");
        }


        lbltargetDay0Assigned.click(function (e) {
           targetDay0Assigned.click();
           lbltargetDay0Assigned.removeClass("ui-state-active");
            if (targetDay0Assigned.is(":checked")) {
                lbltargetDay0Assigned.addClass("ui-state-active");
            }
        });

        lbltargetDay1Assigned.click(function (e) {
           targetDay1Assigned.click();
            lbltargetDay1Assigned.removeClass("ui-state-active");
            if (targetDay1Assigned.is(":checked")) {
                lbltargetDay1Assigned.addClass("ui-state-active");
            }
        });
```